# Showing that a radial solution to the 3-dimensional wave equation can be written in a "clever" way

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Let $\square u = 0$ be the wave equation in $\mathbb R^3$, where $\square$ is the wave operator $\square = \partial_t^2 - \Delta_x$. Let $u \in C^2(\mathbb R^3 \times [0, \infty))$ be a solution of this wave equation that is radial with respect to $x \in \mathbb R^3$ (i.e. knowing $|x|$ and $t$, we already know $u(x, t)$). I know want to show that there exists a function $F \in C^2(\mathbb R)$ so that

$$u(x, t) = \frac{F(t + |x|) - F(t - |x|)}{|x|} \qquad \text{for } x \in \mathbb R^3 \backslash \{0\}, t \geq 0$$

Now I was given the hint that I might consider $\tilde u(|x|, t) := u(x, t)$ and consider the fact that $\tilde u(r, t)$ can be extended  to an even function $\tilde u \in C^2(\mathbb R \times [0, \infty))$ (even with respect to $r$).

Now I assuming that I've extended $\tilde u$ in such a prescribed way, I'm not sure how to continue. I know I somehow want to find an $F$ as above and I (probably) need $\tilde u$ to construct it. I've been thinking that there's maybe a clever trick of writing $u$, i.e. something like $u(x, t) = \frac{\tilde u(|x|, t)}{2} + \frac{\tilde u(-|x|, t)}{2}$ (which already "looks" somewhat like the desired equation), just something more general? But I'm not entirely sure.

Edit: Maybe I need to apply d'Alembert's formula to $\tilde u$? If a radial $u$ satisfies the wave equation $\square u = 0$ in the $3+1$-dimensional case, does $\tilde u$ as defined above actually satisfy $\square \tilde u = 0$ (in the 1+1-dimensional case)? Because that would give me some function $f$ that might help?

Comment: I like how this is done in the book on PDEs by Olver : https://books.google.es/books?id=aQ8JAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thank you. As it seems there are many pages missing in the Google preview of the book, could you maybe link (or if it's not available maybe quote/rephrase) the exact passage where he does this? I spontaneously can't seem to find it in the Google preview of the book.

Comment: Sure, sorry about that. Search for the keyword "spherical waves". There is a section with this name at page 552.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Not a problem. I found the passage. So if I understand the author correctly, then the solution immediately follows from the d'Alembert's formula because the 3-dimensional wave equation reduces to the 1-dimensional one for radial solutions? In other words if $u$ is radial and solves the $3$-dimensional equation, then $\tilde u(x, t) := u(|x|, t)$ (evenly extended to $\mathbb R \times [0, \infty)$) solves the $1$-dimensional wave equation, and we can immediately apply d'Alembert? Just so I understand it correctly. Thank you again.

Comment: It is $ru(t, r)$, not $u$, that solves D'Alembert equation. That's why this formula is dimension dependent and it does not work as is in $R^2$, for instance

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Ok thank you. I think I understand it then.

Answer (score 3):

First, let's prove that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\Delta u = & u_{rr}+\frac{2}{r}u_{r}.
\end{eqnarray*}

We have $u(\boldsymbol{x},t)=w(|\boldsymbol{x}|,t)$ with $r=|\boldsymbol{x}|$. Starting with the expression for $u_x$:
\begin{eqnarray*}
u_{x} & = & w_{x}\\
 & = & w_{r}r_{x}\\
 & = & w_{r}\frac{x}{r}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Now, let's find $u_{xx}$:
\begin{eqnarray*}
u_{xx} & = & w_{rr}\frac{x^{2}}{r^{2}}+w_{r}\left(\frac{1}{r}-\frac{x^{2}}{r^{3}}\right)\\
 & = & w_{rr}\frac{x^{2}}{r^{2}}+w_{r}\left(\frac{1}{r}-\frac{x^{2}}{r^{3}}\right).
\end{eqnarray*}

Now, we can compute $\Delta u$:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\Delta u & = & \boldsymbol{{\color{red}w_{rr}\frac{x^{2}}{r^{2}}}}+w_{r}\left(\frac{1}{r}-\frac{x^{2}}{r^{3}}\right)+\boldsymbol{{\color{red}w_{rr}\frac{y^{2}}{r^{2}}}}+w_{r}\left(\frac{1}{r}-\frac{y^{2}}{r^{3}}\right)+\boldsymbol{{\color{red}w_{rr}\frac{z^{2}}{r^{2}}}}+w_{r}\left(\frac{1}{r}-\frac{z^{2}}{r^{3}}\right)\\
 & = & w_{rr}+w_{r}\left(\frac{3}{r}\right)+w_{r}\left(-\frac{x^{2}}{r^{3}}-\frac{y^{2}}{r^{3}}-\frac{z^{2}}{r^{3}}\right)\\
 & = & w_{rr}+w_{r}\left(\frac{3}{r}\right)-w_{r}\left(\frac{1}{r}\right)\\
 & = & u_{rr}+\frac{2}{r}u_{r}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Next, let's consider
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left(ru\right)_{tt} & = & ru_{tt}\\
 & = & r\Delta u\\
 & = & r\left(u_{rr}+\frac{2}{r}u_{r}\right)\\
 & = & ru_{rr}+2u_{r}.\\
\left(ru\right)_{rr} & = & \left(u+ru_{r}\right)_{r}\\
 & = & u_{r}+u_{r}+ru_{rr}\\
 & = & ru_{rr}+2u_{r}.
\end{eqnarray*}

So, $ru$ satisfies the one-dimensional wave equation. Then
$$ru=F(r+ct)+G(r-ct).$$